# Error when trying to set build status

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins v1.629, GitHub Plugin v1.13.3. An SSH key was set up and SSH'ing git@github.com is successfully authenticated.

Pre/Post build events: Set build status [to "Pending"] on GitHub commit fail to execute.

Here's the main part of the exception the is thrown:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubServerConfig$1 applyNullSafe
WARNING: Failed to login with creds 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.github.com/user
```

After some digging, I got to the Jenkins Configure System page, and under GitHub Plugin Configuration, I am unable to perform either of the following:

- Set credentials for the GitHub Server Config (no matter what I do, the Credentials combo box remains empty)
- Delete the GitHub Server Config (impossible, as it reappears after Save)

Bug of Feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lack of replies for quite a few months, I'll sum up by saying the desired behavior was to link Jenkins to GitHub commits such that the CI builder will mark a GitHub commit with either a green V (success) or a red X (failure).

I couldn't achieve this behavior with the GitHub Plugin, not even in 1.4+ versions (which were reported as should-be-working-now).

Eventually I managed to achieve the desired behavior via the [GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin#updates)

Here's an example image from [a good tutorial on the subject](http://jakubstas.com/github-and-jenkins-pull-request-checking/#.VpIo7lV96Uk):

[image]